# Using SWT elements with Slick2D

Tags: java, swt, slick2d

I'm using the Slick2D-framework to render my chess game. So I want to areas on the window, (1) the chess game itself and (2) the information about the game state like time (Label) and moves (in a scrolling list).

But I didn't find any way to use this frameworks side by side. Is there a simple solution to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the SWT to AWT bridge to create a container you can use:

```
Composite container = new Composite(shell, SWT.EMBEDDED);
// TODO: setLayoutData as appropriate

Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(container);
frame.add(container);

// Use frame for the CanvasGameContainer
```

There is some more discussion [here](http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=13867)